# Clicked Table Row Returns NaN

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to identify as to what row number the user clicks on and to alert them. I wanted to exempt the table headers from being counted so I have intentionally used the this.rowIndex - 1 but when I click on any row, the alert box is returning a NaN value.

How do you fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#mstrTable {
     border: 1px solid black
}
#mstrTable td, th {
     border: 1px solid black
}

#mstrTable tr.normal td {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
#mstrTable tr.highlighted td {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mstrTable">
     <thead>
      <tr> 
        <th>File Number</th>
        <th>Date1</th>
        <th>Date2</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Num.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>0</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KCBS</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Approved</td>
        <td>1&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WFLA</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>
        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
(
  function( )
  {
      var trows = document.getElementById("mstrTable").rows;

      for ( var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t )
      {
          trow = trows[t];
          trow.className = "normal";
          trow.onclick = highlightRow;
      }

      function highlightRow(e)
      {
      alert('Row is ' + this.rowIndex-1)
          for ( var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t )
          {
              trow = trows[t];
              trow.className = ( trow == this && trow.className != "highlighted") ? "highlighted" : "normal";
          }
      }
  }
)();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put parentheses around math operations so they take precedence over string concatenation.

```
alert('Row is ' + (this.rowIndex-1))
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ecXLk/)

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked like a charm. Noted for next time!

Answer (score 0):

Change it to  this.rowIndex instead of  this.rowIndex-1.

Comment: I tried that before but the added parathensis per the answer above fixed it. Thanks for your contribution